BlazorWebView without index.html (.net 8)
I have a Blazor project on .NET 8 that I want to use in a Maui app.
I added a Maui app to my solution and added a reference to the Blazor project. However, I'm not sure how to set the HostPage property for the BlazorWebView control since in .NET 8, there is no index.html file. Instead, it has been replaced with App.razor.
Additionally, I'm not sure what values to set for the Selector and ComponentType properties since there is no HTML element to replace.
    <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Components.Routes}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>


add-a-blazorwebview-to-an-existing-app

You can use the MAUI Blazor to use the BlazorWebView. Here is the link about the ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid.
Blazor Hybrid to use desktop and mobile native client frameworks with .NET and Blazor.
In the Blazor Hybrid app, Razor components run natively on the device. Components are rendered to the embedded Web View control through a local interop channel. The component doesn't run in the browser and doesn't involve WebAssembly. Razor components load and execute code quickly, and components have full access to the device's native functionality through the .NET platform.
The root Razor component of the app is located in Main.razor, and Razor compiles it into a type named Main in the application's root namespace. The rest of the Razor components are located in the pages and shared project folders, the same ones used in the default Blazor web template. The app's static web property index.html is located in the wwwroot folder.
